# Get the first three digits in each gap

Tags: python, regex

Just started learning regex. I have problem here.

This is my code so far.

```
match = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}', string)
```

I know i will get each third number. But i dont know how to tell only each gap.

I have a string which looks like this:

```
string = "24812949 2472198 4271748 12472187"
```

I want a result like this:

```
["248", "247", "427", "124"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b`. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
match = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}', string)
```

OR

Negative lookbehind assertion. `(?<!\S)` Asserts that the match won't be preceded by a non-space character.

```
match = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d{1,3}', string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `\b` as word boundaries:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}', string)
['248', '247', '427', '124']
```

But if your string is always in this form, you can do without regex:

```
>>> [i[:3] for i in string.split()]
['248', '247', '427', '124']
```

Comment: Yeah i knew i could use `[i[:3] for i in string.split()]` . But i am trying to learn regex expressions ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised no one thinks about consuming the rest of the number instead of worrying about the boundary:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d{1,3})\d*', string)
['248', '247', '427', '124']
```

By capturing the first 3 digits (or less in case the number is smaller), and match the rest of the digits, there is no way the next match can happen in the middle of a number. When the previous match ends, the next character after it, if any, must be non-digit, and since the engine scans from left to right, the next match will start at the beginning of a string of digits.

`re.findall` function also returns only the content in the capturing groups when there is at least 1 capturing group in the regex, which smooths out the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))\d{1,3}
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/22

```
match = re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<=\s))\d{1,3}', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution:-

```
string="24812949 2472198 4271748 12472187"
match = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}', string)
print match
```

Output:-['248', '247', '427', '124']